# Check Application logs on AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, logging

I have a Python-Flask application that has been dockerized and deployed on AWS.
I have also added logs to the application. So after deployment where can I check the logs on AWS Console?
I want to check the logs when the hosted application does some operations and the backend API is logging the information of the calls.
Basically, the statements that I've logged using the python `logging` module.
e.g: `logging.info(...)`

Comment: Have you checked in CloudWatch Logs and then Log groups?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But yes. I have checked those. They're logs of the event when the code is building on AWS CodeBuild.
I want to check the logs when the hosted application does some operations and the backend API is logging the information of the calls. 
Basically, the statements that I've logged using the python `logging` module.
e.g: `logging.info(...)`

Comment: Where did you deploy your app to? How does you infrastructure setup look like?

Comment: most likely the logs are in the docker container as long as you didnt use an Cloudwatch appender with your logging framework.

Comment: You can find the application logs in the docker container. First execute `docker ps -a` and check the container id of your flask application and afterwards enter `docker logs <container_id>`

Comment: @BastianKlein I have setup a GitHub WebHook that deploys code whenever merged.
So it deploys using an AWS pipeline. So really have just setup that connection.

Comment: Ok but where do you deploy it to? Plain EC2, ECS, EKS? Depending on that, you might need to setup the log forwarding to Cloudwatch yourself. For example when you use plain EC2 with a Docker installation you can use the [Cloudwatch Logging Driver for Docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/). When you use that everything logged to standard out will be forwarded to Cloudwatch.

Comment: Plain ECS2.
Sure. I'll setup the logging to forward it that way.
Thanks.